# ASP Push Notifications: limit time response

Tags: asp.net, timeout, push-notification

I'm developing a .NET application which communicate with a JS client through Event-source.

It's works pretty well but I have a problem:

If a client disconnects when the server is writing, the server keeps being stuck for 10 seconds and gives me an error at the end:

```
The remote host closed the connection. The error code is 0x80070079.
```

This error is normal and I catch it, but I would like to avoid the  10 seconds or at least limit it to 1 or 2 seconds.

My code is like this:

```
 if (ctx.Response.IsClientConnected)
 {
      ctx.Response.Write("data: " + e.json + "\n\n");
 }
```

I try with `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3"/>` but it doesn't work...

Any idea?

Valentin :)

Comment: Is this an asp.net page or web service?

Comment: page I guess....
My class starts like this :
`code
public class PushProvider : IHttpHandler {

    private HttpContext ctx;
    
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
}
}
`

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a need for a minimum timeout based on connections' unreliability.

I don't know your code logic and architecture exactly but you can convert your operations to work asynchronously.